# Where is the ARP cache on Linux?

Tags: linux, arp

Where, in memory, does the ARP cache exist? I tried searching it up online but didn't find anything.

Comment: @Gilles So if I modify `/proc/net/arp`, then I would indirectly modify the ARP cache?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GNU/Linux, unlike MacOSx, uses the `/proc` directory structure, a.k.a. `procfs`, to store system data.  The `arp cache` is located at `/proc/net/arp`  You print the data to `stdout` directly from that system file via:

```
cat /proc/net/arp
```

I realized that you may also want the memory address that the kernel uses to find the arp cache.  The exact address may vary.  However, you can find the memory address table for all arp memory addresses the kernel uses in `/proc/kallsyms`

```
cat /proc/kallsyms |grep arp_
```

May be helpful as well.

Comment: The `/proc` directory does not *store* anything. It *displays* things stored or computed by the kernel, and it sometimes allows modifying those things, but it does not correspond to any storage area. In the case of the ARP cache, you can view a text rendering of it through `/proc/net/arp`, but what you're seeing is some kernel data structures that have been pretty-printed, you are not directly seeing some file that constitutes the content of the cache.

Comment: This is one place where “GNU/Linux” is wrong. You're referring to the kernel, the kernel is only called “Linux”.

Comment: is it possible to modify `/proc/net/arp` ? I keep getting `cat: write: Input/output error`
and echoing into it doesn't seem to change it.
Is there another utility to change it?
I cannot run `arp` or `if` in BusyBox v0.60.0