# Can I get the IP address of device using MAC address? or logs of IP used by MAC address?

Tags: debian, ip, mac-address, arp, syntax

I been using debian linux version Stretch it seems arp command is helpful but it only collect those online devices

Comment: No, unless you've had some software which logs such information previously installed and running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the ARP cache on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1272010/where-is-the-arp-cache-on-linux)

Comment: appreciate your input guys, Thank you